# Facebook api permission issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am having problems with the Facebook Graph API when trying to call the webservice for publishing a wall post for a user.

I have correctly authenticated my user with my app and it shows that I have permission for "Post to my Wall" in privacy settings.

I call the webservice URL http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed and use these as parameters:

- access_token=xxxxxxx  (access token back from authenticating)
- message=test message

Everytime I get a 403 error from the webservice

> {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200)
>   The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action"}}

What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure why I was getting this error, but as I am using Ruby on Rails I tried the Facebook Graph API gem [fp_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) and it worked a treat.

Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it sounds like either the access token is incorrect or lacks the publish_stream permission.  (You said you're providing a token with that permission, but since that's the error message it's worth double checking.)

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions.